# MVC Render Speedup

Tags: asp.net-mvc, performance, view

I just hooked up the [mvc-mini-profiler](http://code.google.com/p/mvc-mini-profiler/) (thanks SO!) on my site and was looking around to see how well I've done up to this point (it's my first major bout with linq to entities and mvc).  So far everything is looking good, however I'm always looking for ways to improve response times.  At this point it looks like the only major boost I could get would be from reducing the time it takes to render the individual views on each of my pages.

[image: profiler screeny]

You can see from my screeny that the rendering of the `Blog` view is the longest running task.  I know that 30ms is already really quick, but I'm betting there are still some tricks I can pull to get these numbers even lower.

So the question is this: **How can I reduce view render times?**  I know that caching of dynamic views into something like the `HttpRuntime.Cache` can help, but I'm even seeing several ms durations for static view rendering.  What techniques do you use to lower the render times of your views?

Comment: Are you building objects in the view from the db? It's hard to offer suggestions without any idea of what is going on in your code.

Comment: Can you run your test again but make sure that you're running the MVC app under `Release`. How complex is `Blog`? Is it calling multiple child actions or partials?

Comment: @TravisJ In some of them, yes.  In others I'm just getting static views.

Comment: @Omar I am currently running this under release.  Also it's calling one partial view.

Comment: Is it possible to build those objects from your controller and then pass them in? I would assume this would be faster, especially if you only build/pass the relevant parts in a typed blog model.

Comment: @TravisJ My bad, I interpreted what you said incorrectly.  In some views I am creating the objects in the controller and passing them in.  However I do loop on the objects within the view.

Comment: See if you can strip out unnecessary parts of those objects when you pass them in and use something like ViewBag.strippedObject to send in a list of the new type.

Comment: How on earth are you doing 8 sql queries and rendering a page in 30ms?! Are you running this on some kind of supercomputer with the entire database cached in memory? That's awesome!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**I suggest 2 things (if you don't have it done yet)...**

1. **Remove unused ViewEngines**. So if your project uses only the razor view engine, do this in the global.asax on Application_Start();

   ```
   ViewEngines.Engines.Clear();
   ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new RazorViewEngine());
   ```

   or

   ```
   ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new WebFormViewEngine());
   ```

   if you use the WebFormsViewEngine only
2. The biggest improvment is to use the [OutputCacheAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.outputcacheattribute.aspx) to cache the html. I dont think your Blog changes on every Request ;)

   ```
   public class BlogController : Controller
   {
       [OutputCache]
       public ActionResult Index()
       {
          // do something here
          return View();
       }
   }
   ```

You can set the cache-duration and more. Check out: [MSDN - OutputCacheAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.outputcacheattribute.aspx).

Comment: What would cause `[OutputCache]` to ignore caching?  When I set the duration to 60, it looks like it takes longer for every time after the first render (the time on each render is equal to the time taken for the first render: it looks like it's recompiling every time now).

Comment: Not really clear what you mean (too tired maybe) ;). Put a breakpoint on your "return View()" to check if your CacheAttribute Settings work. No performance gain ? There should be a better loading time. Please response, cause this should work.

Comment: I'll take a look at this when I'm done at work.  I'm actually thinking that it might **look** like it's running just as slow, but in fact the mini-profiler results themselves are probably being cached as well.  I'll laugh if that's it.  Also I'm only using razor so I'll test the impact of your first suggestion while I'm at it.

Comment: Yep, the mini profiler is caching the "mini-profiled" result.  I haven't yet figured out a way to get around this yet, but it does look like using `OutputCache` is speeding it up.

Comment: Do you have any numbers on how much time you save per request by going from e.g. 3 view engines to 1? How does it compare to a DB or service round trip? Are we talking only 1 millisecond or 100 ms?